# What's the different between Config Subsystem(CSS) and Blueprint in Opendaylight?

Tags: sdn, blueprint, opendaylight, ietf-netmod-yang

The current opendaylight project I am working on doesn't use blueprint to do the dependency injection. Instead of that, it seems like a yang model is used to do that, which is defined under that bundle project.

After searching around, I realized this is part of Config Subsystem (CSS).

So my question is

(1) What's the main usage different between Config Subsystem(CSS) and Blueprint in Opendaylight in the real production?

(2) If it's possible, can we use blueprint to replace the CSS?

Comment: which version of ODL you are using?

Comment: BROCADE SDN CONTROLLER 3.0.3 and based on 1.7.1 boron rs1